# Access data from json fetch outside of function

Tags: json, swift

I have tried for many hours to fetch data and then be able to access the data from outside of the fetching function without any success. Feel free to ask me for any more information, but the following are my code.

This is my singleton class ->

```
class QuestionClass{
    var q: Question?
    static let sharedInstance = QuestionClass()
    private init(){

    }

    func fetchUser(completion: @escaping ([Question]?) -> ()){
            let url = URL(string: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10.")!
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        // parse json data and return it
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        let jsonDict = try decoder.decode(DATA.self, from: data)
                        completion(jsonDict.results)
                    } catch let parseErr {
                        completion(nil)
                        print("JSON Parsing Error", parseErr)
                    }
                }
            })
            task.resume()
    }
}
```

This is done in the viewController

```
       questionC.fetchUser {
            result in 
            if let temp = result{
                self.questionC.q = temp[0]
                var t = 0
                for (index, _) in temp[self.currentQuestion].incorrect_answers.enumerated(){
                    arrayNumbers.append(index)
                    t = index + 1
                }
                arrayNumbers.append(t)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    for item in temp[self.currentQuestion].incorrect_answers{
                        let indexNumber = Int.random(in: 0 ... arrayNumbers.count-1)
                        self.view.addSubview(self.makeButtonWithText(text: item, x:locations[arrayNumbers[indexNumber]]._x, y:locations[arrayNumbers[indexNumber]]._y))
                            arrayNumbers.remove(at: indexNumber)
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.questionField.text = temp[self.currentQuestion].question
                    self.view.addSubview(self.makeButtonWithText(text: temp[self.currentQuestion].correct_answer, x:locations[arrayNumbers[0]]._x, y:locations[arrayNumbers[0]]._y))
                }
            }
        }
        print(questionC.q)
        print(questionC.q?.correct_answer)
```

In the ending lines i want to print out the values from my fetched data. But they are nil, any idea why?

Comment: You are trying to access questionC object outside completion handler.

Comment: Yes that is true. Any idéa how i can access data that are within the callback outside the callback function?

Comment: If you want to wait till data gets loaded and then continue execution, you could use `DispatchGroup`

Comment: You cannot do that without making your function asynch. Add callback function and pass data to that call back function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dispatchGroup did the trick (big thanks to MjZac for pointing me in the right direction). The problem seemed to be that I tried to access questionC.q before fetchUser was finished.

Answer (score 1):

Move them inside `result in if let temp = result{` block

```
questionC.fetchUser {
    result in if let temp = result{
        self.questionC.q = temp[0]
        var t = 0
        for (index, _) in temp[self.currentQuestion].incorrect_answers.enumerated(){
            arrayNumbers.append(index)
            t = index + 1
        }
        arrayNumbers.append(t)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            for item in temp[self.currentQuestion].incorrect_answers{
                let indexNumber = Int.random(in: 0 ... arrayNumbers.count-1)
                self.view.addSubview(self.makeButtonWithText(text: item, x:locations[arrayNumbers[indexNumber]]._x, y:locations[arrayNumbers[indexNumber]]._y))
                    arrayNumbers.remove(at: indexNumber)
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.questionField.text = temp[self.currentQuestion].question
            self.view.addSubview(self.makeButtonWithText(text: temp[self.currentQuestion].correct_answer, x:locations[arrayNumbers[0]]._x, y:locations[arrayNumbers[0]]._y))
        }


        print(questionC.q)
        print(questionC.q?.correct_answer)

    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that works but that also requires me to always run the function in order to access the data which i don't want to. I want to be able to access the data outside the callback not from the inside.

Comment: this is an asynchronous call you have to start the next work from there

Comment: So there is no way i can somehow fetch data and then store that data till later in the program.

Comment: `questionC` is an object check it's properties before you call load or post full code context